# Rails: How to handle model subclassing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There are ten ways to do anything but what is the best practice approach to organizing the `Document` and `Section` models described below in Rails?

Documents can have n number of sections. Each `Section` can be a specialized type of section with its own attributes and associations differing from other sections. And each `Document` needs to track a section order state for all of the sections associated with it regardless of type.

I could create model classes for each `Section` type and associate them on `Document` as has_many `SectionTypeA`, has_many `SectionTypeA` and write a sorting mechanism to put together a sorted collection of all types for the given document.

I looked into Single Table Inheritance. But the STI approach seems questionable when the specialized attributes are more complicated than a few string or integer fields. Sections will have attributes that map to database text columns and their own section has_many, has_one associations.

Here's a rough outline of the elements described:

```
Document
  Sections
  -Section Type A
    Title, freeform text
  -Section Type B
    Title, collection of urls
  -Section Type C
    Title, collection of images with title and collection of image comments
```

Comment: Have you seen [this excellent question and interesting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails) about STI? If your different section types share much code, and only the data differs, you might give STI a shot. But if the common denominator is just that `Title` attribute, you might want to just create separate associations for each type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many classes is too many? Rails STI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677924/how-many-classes-is-too-many-rails-sti)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it could be solved with a reverse polymorphic association like:

```rb
# Models
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :document_sections
  has_many  :freeform_sections, 
            :through => :document_sections, 
            :source => :section, 
            :source_type => 'FreeformSection'

  def add_section(section)
    self.freeform_sections << section if section.is_a? FreeformSection
  end
end

class DocumentSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :section, :polymorphic => true
end

class FreeformSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :document_section, :as => :section
  has_one :document, :through => :document_section
end

# Migrations
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :documents do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateDocumentSections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :document_sections do |t|
      t.integer :section_id
      t.string :section_type
      t.references :document

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateFreeformSections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :freeform_sections do |t|
      t.references :section

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# Usage
document = Document.create :name => 'My Doc'
document.freeform_sections << FreeformSection.new
document.add_section FreeformSection.new
document.document_sections
document.freeform_sections
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Maybe you can create a 'sectionable' type for your different `Section` types and put those in one polymorphic association in `Document`.

Comment: My understanding of polymorphic associations is that they're useful for linking a single model as belongs_to multiple other models. In this case, I have multiple kinds of section with varying attributes and associations that belongs_to one document.